# How to use .env variables in app.html in SvelteKit?

Tags: sveltekit

how I can use the environments variables in script inside app.html. I tried importing the key with `import { PUBLIC_KEY } from '$env/dynamic/public';`   but it doesn't work

Comment: The question is, why do you need it there? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm initialising the Facebook sdk, I've tried to do this in various ways but this is the only way I understand it works. To initialise I need an PUBLIC_KEY , which I store. in the .env

Comment: Just do it in a `+layout.svelte`.

Comment: Now in this code I have a problem: window is undefined  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
   FB.init({
    appId: '',
    autoLogAppEvents: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v18.0',
   });
     
  };
 }

Comment: I'm sorry I don't cnow how to add code block to comments

Comment: Then you should find out why that is and what to do about it. Hint: It probably has to do with server-side rendering. Check [`browser`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-environment-browser) or maybe use [`onMount`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#onmount).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255346/discussion-between-davidf-and-h-b).

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is not intended for discussions. Either find relevant questions or ask a new one if none exist. Maybe this can also be done in `app.html`, I just would not recommend it, as it mostly lives outside the SvelteKit lifecycle.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77143537/why-fb-init-running-erratically-in-the-file-layout-svelte