# Why FB.init() running erratically in the file +layout.svelte?

Tags: sveltekit

I am writing an application on SvelteKit using FacebookSDK. I have this problem that when I use the code

```
<body data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover">
    <div style="display: contents">%sveltekit.body%</div>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: '-------',
                autoLogAppEvents: true,
                xfbml: true,
                version: 'v18.0',
            });
            console.log("Facebook is init2");
        };
        console.log("Facebook is init1");
    </script>
    
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>   
</body>
```

inside the `app.html` file it works stable, the logs show first the first one, then the second one, but as I understand SvelteKit is not designed to use the `app.html` file in this way. I tried to put this code in `+layout.svelte` file, but it starts to work unstable, once in 10 tries initialisation ends(Facebook is init2), it is written out to console. I don't understand why this happens
Here's some code that doesn't work properly

```
<script>

import '../global.css';
import Footer from '$lib/Footer.svelte';
import FacebookInit from '$lib/FacebookInit.svelte';
import FacebookScript from '$lib/FacebookScript.svelte';
```

it is an `+layout.svelte` file.

```
<script >

import { onMount } from 'svelte';

onMount(() => {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '---------',
            autoLogAppEvents: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v18.0',
        });
        console.log("Facebook is init2");       
    };
    console.log("Facebook is init1");

    
});
```

It is `FacebookInit.svelte`

```
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

It is `FacebookScript.svelte`

I've already tried many different variations of the code layout

Comment: You might want to include the exact code you *use in the layout which does not work* rather than the code you *don't use which does work*.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a script order issue. The FB script has to run after you set the callback function.

You could e.g. add the `<script>` tag dynamically after setting `window.fbAsyncInit` in `onMount`. To have the script already download in the background, you could add a [`rel=preload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload) link to the `<head>` (this should also be possible in the layout via `<svelte:head>`).

```js
onMount(() => {
    window.fbAsyncInit = () => console.log(FB);

    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js');
    script.setAttribute('async', '');
    script.setAttribute('defer', '');
    script.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    return () => script.remove();
});
```

If the script does not run, it's probably due to a restrictive content security policy.

Comment: Can you please add little more detail?

Comment: There already should be questions and answers elsewhere (e.g. how to add a script tag in code).

Comment: This answer not solving the problem. still facing the same issue as he mentioned.

Comment: I just tried it, it's not complicated and it works.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is when we are initialising  window.fbAsyncInit with app ID from .env file in .svelte file we are getting an error that FB.login called before init. Randomly facing this issue

Comment: I added an answer that helped me to fix the issue. Am not sure it is a correct way that's why I didn't posted please check it. If it won't help for other users I will remove

Answer (score 0):

I removed `window.fbAsyncInit`  and initialized FB directly in `+layout.svelte` file it worked

```js
onMount(async () => {
    const appID = PUBLIC_FB_APP_ID
    await addScript(`
    //This one solved the issue that "fb.login() called before fb.init()"
    FB.init({
        appId: ${appID},  
        cookie: true, // enable cookies
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v18.0' //Graph API version
    });
    
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js,
            fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    })(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');`);
    new DarkMode();
    storeQuilEditor.set(null);

    if ($page.url.pathname != '/whatsapp/templates') getWhatsappMessageTemplates();

    checkUserState();
    //getProductOfCatelog() // hinding this we are not using right now
});
```

function to add script in promise

```js
export function addScript(code:any) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = true;
    
    try {
      s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    } catch (e) {
      s.text = code;
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    }
    s.addEventListener('load', resolve);
    s.addEventListener('error', reject);

    document.body.appendChild(s);
  });
}
```